# Not a member of global namespace?

Tags: c++, windows, file-io

I have the error:

> error C2039: 'read' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
>   and 
>   error C2661: 'Calc::SymString::read' : no overloaded function takes 3 arguments
>   from the line:
>    if (::read(fd_sock, &size, 4) != 4)

This error and similar ones appear quite a lot in my code. Does anyone know what the problem could be?
I am using Windows Visual Studio 2010 and I am migrating code from Unix.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: "No overloaded function...." means you apparently have overloaded functions and you're trying to pass one or more of them 3 arguments, but none of them accept 3. Check your function prototypes, calls, and definitions for errors. You might want to post the specific code to get real answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

read() is a UNIX function defined (in LINUX) in unistd.h - all the documentation I have read indicates it is not a standard C function.  That may be why it is compiling in UNIX but not in Windows.

In UNIX `read()` takes a file descriptor, but the equivalent construct in Windows is a "handle".

Do you really need low level file descriptor I/O in your program?  Can you use `fread`, which is a standard C function?

[This Microsoft support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/99173) describes the types of file handles available in Windows:

```
There are multiple types of file handles that can be opened using 
the Win32 API and the C Run-time:

   Returned Type  File Creation API      API Set
   ---------------------------------------------
   HANDLE         CreateFile()           Win32
   HFILE          OpenFile()/_lcreat()   Win32
   int            _creat()/_open()       C Run-time
   FILE *         fopen()                C Run-time
```

Comment: Ah that is something that is really helpful! Actually I think the easiest way for me to change it may be to use this source:      http://suacommunity.com/dictionary/read-entry.php. It is a porting dictionary that has been extremely helpful. I don't know why I did not think of it in the first place! Thanks!

Comment: @JorelEstrada If you find AB's answer helpful, you should vote for it by clicking the up arrow and/or accept it by clicking the check mark.

Comment: @Code-Guru Because I have no reputation yet, I cannot vote up. I did mark it as an answer though! And for anyone reading looking for how I actually remedied the problem, I included <io.h> as a header, and I changed read to _read and write to _write. This info was found through the porting dictionary I referenced earlier

Comment: @JorelEstrada Ahh...I forgot about getting that ability with enough rep. My apologies. I wish I could help you out, but I used up all my votes for the day already ;-(

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft declares the Unix-style I/O functions in `io.h`.

Try including that header - you may get a bunch of warnings about using deprecated names (MS would prefer you use the name `_read()`). If so, you may want to define the macro `_POSIX_` which should quiet those warnings.